# Make application layer loosely coupled

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I have a **Java Spring-boot** application which has layers(**packages**):

- Controller(controller class)
- Service (business logic)
- Domain (database layer)

Inside My `Domain` I have two database classes

- MysqlDBManager
- MongoDBManager

I have many classes in my `service package` which uses methods of both `MysqlDBManager` as well as `MongoDBManager`.

**If** **I use instances** of `MysqlDBManager' and`MongoDBManager` on my service class directly then **service** layer will get **tightly coupled** with **domain** layer.

To solve this problem I have created a class named `**DBManager**` in my **domain** package which behaves as a proxy class which calls `MysqlDBManager' and`MongoDBManager` based on the use case internally.

Now service layer, instead of calling `MysqlDBManager' and`MongoDBManager`directly they call`DBManager`, which internally calls`MysqlDBManager' and `MongoDBManager`.

Hence now my service class is not tightly coupled with domain layer.

Below are my classes which resembles my use-case.

**MongoDBManager class:**

```
 Class  MongoDBManager {
       public saveUserDocs(String docs) {
         //.....
       }
    }
```

**MysqlDBManager class:**

```
Class  MysqlDBManager {
       public saveUserData(List<String> rows) {
         //.....
       }
    }
```

**DBManager class:**

```
 Class  DBManager {

           @Autowired 
           private MysqlDBManager mysqlDBManager;
           @Autowired 
           private MongoDBManager mongoDBManager;

           public saveUserData(List<String> rows) {
             mysqlDBManager.saveUserData(rows);
           }

           public saveUserDocs(String docs) {
             mongoDBManager.saveUserDocs(docs);
           }
        }
```

**Service class:**

```
class Service {
    @Autowired 
    private DBManager dBManager;

    //....... code here
    dBManager.saveUserData(rows);
    dBManager.saveUserDocs(docs);
}
```

**My Question is**:

Is this (as explained above) a good way to make my application layers loosely coupled or their exist better ways to do this?

Comment: Always follow SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) to make application layers loose couples.

Comment: Take a look at "Command Pattern"

Answer (score 6):

You approach is fine, it is look like some sort of Facade design pattern, but I would recommend more traditional way.

You already have spring as IoC container, so all you have to do is to extract interfaces from your `*DBManager`-classes and tell spring about your implementations. Then you will be able to inject an actual implementation using an interface, which in turn might resides in a totally different package. Therefore coupling will cease to exist.

Here is an example.

DataStorage contract:

```
package root;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserDataStorage {
    void saveUserData(List<String> rows);
}
```

DocumentStorage contract:

```
package root;

public interface UserDocumentStorage {
    void saveUserDocs(String docs);
}
```

DataStorage implementation:

```
package root.domain;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import root.UserDataStorage;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class MysqlDBManager implements UserDataStorage {
    @Override
    public void saveUserData(List<String> rows) {
        System.out.println("Saving data....");
    }
}
```

DocumentStorage implementation:

```
package root.domain;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import root.UserDocumentStorage;

@Service
public class MongoDBManager implements UserDocumentStorage {
    @Override
    public void saveUserDocs(String docs) {
        System.out.println("Saving docs....");
    }
}
```

Then your service classes might look like this (please pay attention there is no reference to `domain` package:

```
package root.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import root.UserDataStorage;
import root.UserDocumentStorage;

import java.util.Collections;

@Service
public class MyService {

    private final UserDataStorage dataStorage;
    private final UserDocumentStorage documentStorage;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(UserDataStorage dataStorage, UserDocumentStorage documentStorage) {
        this.dataStorage = dataStorage;
        this.documentStorage = documentStorage;
    }

    public void callMe() {
        this.dataStorage.saveUserData(Collections.emptyList());
        this.documentStorage.saveUserDocs("Document1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

IMHO there is a better way, The interfaces help you to have loosely couple layers, here is an example:

```
interface DocsDBManager {
   void saveUserDocs(String docs);
}

interface UserDBManager {
   void saveUserData(List<String> rows);
}

interface DBManager extends DocsDBManager, UserDBManager {
}
```

And you must to implement them:

```
class  MongoDBManager implements DocsDBManager {
   public void saveUserDocs(String docs) {
     //.....
   }
}

class  MysqlDBManager implements UserDBManager {
   public void saveUserData(List<String> rows) {
     //.....
   }
}
```

And:

```
class  DBManagerBase implements DBManager  {

       @Autowired 
       private DocsDBManager docsDBManager;
       @Autowired 
       private UserDBManager userDBManager;

       public void saveUserData(List<String> rows) {
            userDBManager.saveUserData(rows);
       }

       public void saveUserDocs(String docs) {
           docsDBManager.saveUserDocs(docs);
       }
 }
```

And finally:

```
class Service {
    @Autowired 
    private DBManager dBManager;

    //....... code here
    dBManager.saveUserData(rows);
    dBManager.saveUserDocs(docs);
}
```

Comment: Oh, neat solution!